# simple example about django REST CRUD

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, crud

I'm working on a Django REST API project for a restaurant.

I have to get client requests and for some requests send model objects and for the update or delete requests send a feedback to the client.

Suppose that my `models.py` is like:

```
# models.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Table(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    is_free = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.id, self.name, self.is_free)


class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    table_id = models.ForeignKey(Table, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_price = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.order_id, self.total_price)
```

I want to send a list of all orders for client GET request, send feedback for the update and delete requests, and send True or False whether if a specific table with an id that sent from the client is free or not.

unfortunately, I'm confused after reading so many documents.

Would you please give a simple example to achieve these purposes?

After that can you give me an example of how to serialize a none model object for clients uses?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the easiest approach is to use a `ModelViewSet` and `ModelSerializer` which will provide the basic CRUD operations.

**serializers.py**

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('order_id', 'table_id', 'total_price')
```

**views.py**

```
class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('table_id',)
```

**urls.py**

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'orders', OrderViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Get all orders:

```
http://host/orders/
```

Get an order by id:

```
http://host/orders/123/
```

Get all orders for a specific table:

```
http://host/orders/?table_id=456
```

Update an order with PUT:

```
# PUT using form data total_price=100
http://host/orders/123/

# Response
{"order_id": 123, "table_id": 456, "total_price": 100}
```

Delete an order with DELETE:

```
# DELETE
http://host/orders/123/

# Response has no content
```

For querying whether a table with a specific id is free, you could use the same approach but with a `TableViewSet`:

```
# Get a table with a specific id
http://host/tables/456/
```

and then evaluate the `is_free` property in the JSON response you get back.

```
# Response
{"id": 456, "name": "table name", "is_free": true}
```

Comment: Thanks Will. when I wanna get all orders for a specific table and put `http://localhost:8000/orders/?table_id=1` in the URL bar, it still shows me all orders!!! why?

Comment: Ah, I think you will need to specify `filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)` in your view. I have updated the answer. Note the trailing comma is significant (it's a tuple) and note that you'll need to add `from rest_framework import filters`

Comment: Yes. of course in the newer version of Django, it changed to: `from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend`  and add `filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)` to the view and also add `'django_filters',` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` ... now it's working.